# My query will not update, but when i refresh in dd it will

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I run the query normally it won't update the **status_order** from `0` to `1`, but when I put a **dd()** function after the query to check if it will update properly, it will give the same result the first time I run the code, but when I refresh the page it will update to a `1`.

Here's how my code usually looks:

```php
public function payment(Request $request){
      $total = 0;
      $orderInfo = $this->getOrderInfo();
      $json2 = array();
        foreach($this->getOrderInfo()->products as $product){
          $total += ($product->price * $product->pivot->order_quantity);
        }
      if(Customer::find(Auth::user()->id)->balance >= $total && $orderInfo !== null){
        if($orderInfo->order_status !== 1){
        $orderInfo->where('customer_id', Auth::user()->id)
                  ->where('order_status', 0)
                  ->update(['order_status' => 1]);
      }
        foreach($orderInfo->products as $product){
          $json = array('order_id' => $product->pivot->order_id,
                        'product_id' => $product->pivot->product_id,
                        'product_name' => $product->name,
                        'price' => $product->price,
                        'quantity' => $product->pivot->order_quantity);
          array_push($json2, $json);
        }
        Customer::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->decrement('balance', $total);
        array_push($json2, array('order_status' => $orderInfo->order_status));
        $productInfo = json_encode($json2, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        OrderHistory::create([
          'customer_id' => Auth::user()->id,
          'orderInfo' => $productInfo
        ]);
        $orderInfo->products()
        ->detach();
        $orderInfo->delete();
        return back();
      }else{
        return "Not enough balance";
      }
  }
}
```

Here's where I put my **dd()** function:

```php
  if($orderInfo->order_status !== 1){
        $orderInfo->where('customer_id', Auth::user()->id)
                  ->where('order_status', 0)
                  ->update(['order_status' => 1]);
          dd($orderInfo->where('customer_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('order_status', 0));
      }
```

The `if($orderInfo->order_status !== 1)` is put in there for me to check if the query would get skipped at all. I have tried to alter the order in which the code is presented, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: truth to be told, i'm confused that this code runs at all. i meant `$orderInfo` is an object given you checked its property `order_status` but then you call `where()` on it as if it is a collection (or model). also its not `laravel-query-builder` but [tag:laravel-eloquent] or just [tag:eloquent] given you have `detach()` there..

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will correct it accordingly.

Comment: @BagusTesa, please check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code produce mass update but doesn't affect your `$orderInfo` model which is loaded when it had `order_status == 0`

```php
$orderInfo = $this->getOrderInfo();
// ...
$orderInfo->where('customer_id', Auth::user()->id)
                  ->where('order_status', 0)
                  ->update(['order_status' => 1]);
// in database data was updated, but $orderInfo is already in memory, so
// $orderInfo->order_status == 0
```

in case you want to get immediately impact on `$orderInfo` try

```php
// if you order can have only one info
$orderInfo->order_status = 1;
$orderInfo->save();

// if order can have multiple info models
$orderInfo->newQuery()->where('customer_id', Auth::user()->id)
                  ->where('order_status', 0)
                  ->update(['order_status' => 1]);
$orderInfo = $orderInfo->fresh();
```

[docs about `fresh()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#refreshing-models)

---

as a sidenote here you're doing duplicate `getOrderInfo()` call

```php
  $orderInfo = $this->getOrderInfo();
  $json2 = array();
  //foreach($this->getOrderInfo()->products as $product) {
  foreach($orderInfo->products as $product) {
    $total += ($product->price * $product->pivot->order_quantity);
  }
```

---

update to clarify about comment to main post

> truth to be told, i'm confused that this code runs at all. i meant
> $orderInfo is an object given you checked its property order_status
> but then you call where() on it as if it is a collection (or model).
> also its not laravel-query-builder but laravel-eloquent or just
> eloquent given you have detach() there.. –  Bagus Tesa

if we dig into `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class there is 'magic' method `__call`

```php
/**
     * Handle dynamic method calls into the model.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
            return $this->$method(...$parameters);
        }

        if ($resolver = (static::$relationResolvers[get_class($this)][$method] ?? null)) {
            return $resolver($this);
        }
        // that's why OP code works
        return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), $method, $parameters);
    }
```

as you can see if model has no method to call it forwards call to `Builder` object (result of `$this->newQuery()`) which is equivalent to `ModelName::query()`

tbh, i agree that calling eloquent from loaded model is a bit frustrating, but it is 'by design'

Comment: This was the solution i was looking for! I am also happy you found the duplicate call!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do a mass update, what this theoretically is, you need to define all the attributes that you want to mass update in the `$fillable` array in your Model. (`OrderInfo` in this case)

Comment: I have tried using the `$fillable` array, instead of the `$guarded` array that i was using, but the result is still the same. And for clarification, I am trying to edit a singular entry in the database.

Comment: mass update does not have anything to do with the amount of values that are updated. Glad you got your answer though.

Comment: I am happy that you took the time to also help me!